# Handling Edit with Conditional Rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I was trying to conditionally render buttons and an edit form with react. The idea behind my code was that upon clicking the edit button, the edit and delete buttons change to say save and cancel and the h5 (header) fields that are initially populated by a get method change to textareas with the original default values. I thought this may be a decent way to do it, but I was horribly mistaken.

```
const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState({ list: [] });
    const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('/api/User')
            .then(response => {
                setUsers({list:response.data});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }, []);

    const handleDelete = (user) => {

        axios
            .delete(`/api/User/${user.id}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                 window.location.reload(true);
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.log(error)
             })
    }

    const handleEdit = (user) => {       
        setEdit(true);
        return (
        <div className="section" key={user.id}>
            <div className="divider"></div>
                <textarea type="username" className="edit-userName" defaultValue={user.username}></textarea>
                <textarea type="email" className="edit-userName" defaultValue={user.email}></textarea>
                <Button className="btn-save" color="info" onClick={() => handleSave(user)}>Save</Button>
                <Button className="btn-cancel" color="info" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>Cancel</Button>
        </div>
        )
    }

    const handleSave = (user) => {
        axios
            .put(`/api/User/${user.id}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })

        setEdit(false);
    }

     return(
         <div className="container white">
             <h3 className="center"> 
             Manage Users
             <Button className="btn-createUser" color="info">
                 <Link to='/signup'>New User</Link>
             </Button>
             </h3>        
                 {users.list.map(user => (
                     <div className="section" key={user.id}>
                     <div className="divider"></div>
                         <h5 type='username' className="user-userName">{user.username}</h5>
                         <h5 type='email' className="user-userEmail">{user.email}</h5>
                         <Button className="btn-edit" color="info" onClick={() => handleEdit(user)}>Edit</Button>
                         <Button className="btn-delete" color="info" onClick={() => handleDelete(user)}>Delete</Button>
                     </div>
                 ))}
         </div>
     );
 }

 export default Users;
```

Follow-up: I got the render to change the header to textareas and the put is now correctly hitting the endpoint, however the render will open all fields instead of simply the one I press edit on.

```
{users.list.map(user => (
                     <div className="section" key={user.id}>
                     <div className="divider"></div>
                         <h5 type='username' className="user-userName">{user.username}</h5>
                         <h5 type='email' className="user-userEmail">{user.email}</h5>
                         {edit ? (
                         <>
                         <textarea type="username" className="edit-userName" defaultValue={user.username}></textarea>
                         <textarea type="email" className="edit-userName" defaultValue={user.email}></textarea>
                         <Button className="btn-save" color="info" onClick={() => handleSave(user)}>Save</Button>
                         <Button className="btn-cancel" color="info" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>Cancel</Button>
                         </>
                         ) : (
                        <>
                         <Button className="btn-edit" color="info" onClick={() => handleEdit(user.id)}>Edit</Button>
                         <Button className="btn-delete" color="info" onClick={() => handleDelete(user.id)}>Delete</Button>
                        </>
                        )}
                     </div>
                 ))}
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) docs. I'm guessing you have, but you're just not quite implementing it right.

You can set a state when Edit is clicked, which it looks like you are doing. Then you can have two lines of code for each option, using the `Inline If with Logical && Operator` method from the docs and only one button will render. This would go into your .jsx inside the div with classname `divider` for one of your buttons (instead of `<Button ...>Save</Button>`):

```
{!edit && <Button ...>Save</Button>}
{edit && <Button ...>Edit</Button>}
```

or more simply:

```
{edit ? (<Button ...>Edit</Button>) : (<Button ...>Save</Button>)}
```

You can also use the first example from the docs I linked which makes another component which would look like this (outside your `Users` functional component!):

```
// Put all your logic here to figure out what to render
function SaveButton(props) {
  if (props.edit) {
    return <Button ...>Edit</Button>;
  } else {
    return <Button ...>Save</Button>;
  }
}
```

Then in your functional component:

```
<SaveButton edit={edit} />
```

Hopefully this helps you understand how to conditionally render.

Edit to your edit:

To make it only apply to one user, your edit state will need to be more specific. You can make it an array or an object. For example:

```
const [edit, setEdit] = useState({}); // No one is being edited
```

Then when an edit is clicked, you set edit with a key:value pair that resolves to truthy via `setEdit({...edit, [user.id]: true})`

This would make it it fill with `{55: true, 68: true}` (two user ids being edited). The spread operator `...edit` is so you don't lose any other ids being edited.

When you want to revert (edit complete), delete that property or set it to false.

Now, in your line where you are deciding to render the HTML:

```
`{edit ? (`
```

Change it to:

```
`{edit[user.id] ? (`
```

This will make each mapped resource check if the edit state object has a truthy property equal to its ID.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had a small edit above that I was asking for help with I got the render to work but I need it to be specific to a specific user

Comment: Made some changes that should help.

Comment: I attempted to do that but now the edit will never render the edit at all. I completely understand setting a specific id to be true so that you only edit THAT field

Comment: Try posting your code to codesandbox.io, other than that you'll have to debug why your edit[user.id] is always resolving to false. Learning to debug is a huge time saving skill. How to put breakpoints in your code and see the status of your state and variables. This is one reason I don't like in-line if and prefer doing an element variable or another component, it's easier to debug.